# change to a specific screen in awesome wm

Tags: awesome

Is it possible to switch to a specific screen via hotkeys in awesome wm (v4.0)?

Say you have screens *DP-1-2*, *DP-2-2* and *eDP-1*. You now want to switch to screen *DP-1-2* regardless of which screen you are currently on.
Preferably one could use the same technique to also move applications to a specific screen.

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no default bindings for this as far as I know, but the required methods to create them exist:

- focusing a screen directly [`awful.screen.focus`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html#awful.screen.focus).
  Takes a screen object to move focus to.
- moving a client [`client:move_to_screen`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#client:move_to_screen).
  Note that you'll want to add this to the client bindings table, not the global one.

If you want to create the bindings based on the randr output names, you can use the screen objects' [`outputs` property](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html#screen.outputs). This table has the randr output names as *keys*, so it's a bit convoluted to use for this purpose. I'd try something like this:

```lua
for s in screen do
  for out,_ in pairs(s.outputs) do
    if out == "eDP1" then
      globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(globalkeys,
        awful.key({modkey}, "F1", function() awful.screen.focus(s) end))
    elseif out == "DP-1-2" then
      -- ...
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot test it right now, don't have multiple screens available here.

Comment: How exactly do you use the `outputs` property? I tried `property::outputs.name['DP-1-2']` which does not seem to work.

Comment: the documentation to `outputs` is a bit misleading, there is no `name` attribute on it, you have to replace it with the actual name. You also cannot get a screen object from it directly. I've expanded the answer a bit to show how you could use it.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. Still struggling to actually get the screen names. I tried your suggestion however it gives an error ("`bad argument #1 to 'pairs' table expected, got userdata`"). I tried several variations like `s.name`, `s.outputs.name` and `screen.outputs.name` because according to the docs `outputs` should have a table called `name` which includes the screens as keys. As you said the docs seem a bit misleading as neither of the above worked.

Comment: I actually fixed it. I will post the working solution in case anyone else wants to look at it. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by **crater2150** I found a working solution. I post this in case anyone has the same problem.

```
-- set up keybindings based on existing monitors
for s in screen do
  for screen_name, _ in pairs(s.outputs) do
    if screen_name == "eDP-1" then
      globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(globalkeys,
          awful.key({modkey}, "F1", function() awful.screen.focus(s) end))
    elseif screen_name == "DP-2-2" then
      globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(globalkeys,
          awful.key({modkey}, "F2", function() awful.screen.focus(s) end))
    elseif screen_name == "DP-1-2" then
      globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(globalkeys,
          awful.key({modkey}, "F3", function() awful.screen.focus(s) end))
    end
  end
end
```

Simply iterate over all screens and if the ones you are interested in exist, add a keybind that switches to the respective screen.